# program running a boot on BeagleBoneblack

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack

I am having a problem with a small application I developed on the BBB running Debian Image 2017-03-19.

I connected a barcode scanner to the usb port and a 2x16 LCD display to the GPIO controlled by BBBioLib.

I developed an application in C to read a barcode label apply to a race tyre, which find a match on an SQLite table and show the racer name on the display.

Application work great but since the all assembly must work stand alone I need to run the program automatically at boot.

I follow all the instruction on creating a bash program and service but I am getting a strange behaviour.

The display after the welcome message hang up and never change but the application work correctly because all the printf to the consolle get logged correctly and once I exit the application I can check them on the log of the service.

If I restart the service manually everything work fine.

This is the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/read_barcode
```

This is the service code

```
[Unit]
Description=Barcode reader launch
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/barcode.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anyone can help on solving this problem.

Thanks

Carlo

Comment: Are both devices (LCD and reader) running under the same program?
What happens if you run the program after you discover LCD hangs?

Comment: Why don't you run the binary directly instead of calling it from a script?

Comment: Yes, both device run under the same program. I am sending the same LCD string to the console. After the program exit if I check the status of the service I can see the program working correctly except for the LCD.

Comment: I didn't have much experience on how to start a program at boot. I follow several example and they suggest running a script

Answer (score 0):

Run a .service file with `sudo systemctl enable YourService.service` at this location.

```
/etc/systemd/system/
```

Use the `enable` option for systemd .service files to make your source work on boot or a reboot.

Comment: Also...I see this is an older post. You may want to update the image for your BBB at bbb.io/latest-images.